# perform a method every time a tab is selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabview

I have tabview based project. how can I make a view connected to a tab perform a certain method every time the tab is selected?

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the tab var is the main way to make the view appear, you can hook code into:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

or ...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I mistook TabBar for TableView. I'm sorry for that. I let my old answer being here, it might help you in another problem.

The answer that *bryamac* gave you is the right one.

When you click the tab then you probably load some UIView to display some content. For that UIView you must have a controller class. In that controller class there are `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` and `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` methods which you may use.

**Old answer**

What you want to do is make a class to a UITableViewDelegate.

Then you must set this class as the delegate of the UITableView, you can to that in the Interface Builder by right-clicking on the UITableView and dragging its delegate to the class that you have chosen, e.g. its own controller class.

Then you implement this method inside the UITableViewDelegate-class:

```
– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath;
```

More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I think "tab" was asked for - not "table".  A tab bar can have many types of views, not necessarily UiTableViews